# Laravel DomPDF Custom Font Face Shows Square Boxes

Tags: laravel, postman, font-face, dompdf

I am trying to generate a PDF that will contain Chinese characters using dompdf and hence I downloaded the font package and added the following code in my blade.php.

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'simhei';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        src: url('{{base_path().'/public/fonts/'}}'simhei.ttf) format('truetype');
    }

    body {  
        font-family: 'simhei', 'DejaVu Sans', sans-serif; 
    }
```

Next, I tried the API again with Postman. The response body shows square boxes as shown below.

[image]

But if I highlighted the text, it shows the Chinese characters.

[image]

If I save the response as a file in Postman, it also shows square boxes instead of Chinese characters when I opened it in WPS Office.
I have also tried with other font packages including Firefly Sung and msyh. All give the same result.

Comment: This error is indicative of an issue where the font supports the character, but when the font file is embedded in the PDF it's missing the referenced glyph. If you disable font subsetting (`$dompdf = new Dompdf(['isFontSubsettingEnabled' => false]);`) do the characters display correctly?

Comment: I got the workaround from this link: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/79#issuecomment-257003345

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@font-face {
      font-family: 'Firefly Sung';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: url(http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/fonts/cjk/fireflysung.ttf) format('truetype');
    }
    * {
      font-family: Firefly Sung, DejaVu Sans, sans-serif;
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: I got the workaround from this link: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/79#issuecomment-257003345

Comment: Goodjob for this!